# I am trying to get my dynamic buttons to work the same as the buttons that i put on the html.

Tags: javascript

//this function on click will get whatever the user typed into the input box 
   and put it on the dom as a button with a attribute of carModels='whatever the input is'

```
$('#done').on('click',function(){
```

//gets the value the user wrote

```
var input = document.getElementById('box').value;
```

//sets up creating a button

```
    var buttons = $('<button>  </button>');
```

//gives the button tag a attribute of carModels ='input'

```
buttons.attr('carModels',input);
```

//adds the input to the button tag as text on the dom

```
    buttons.html(input)
    console.log(buttons)
     appends what buttons is the the dom
    $('.buttons').append(buttons);
     })
```

//the function uses the giphy api to search through its library of images

```
    $('button').on('click',function(){
```

// lets the click function to know what button to press using the this by finding  ones that one have a value for carModels and puts that value into a variable

```
 var cars = $(this).attr('carModels');
```

//sets the search parameters for the giphy api

```
 var search= 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q='+ cars +
    '&api_key=ropdsAGp3DkXzD5Kb4qmGD3oRmUz716T&limit=10';
```

//calls the api

```
    $.ajax({
    url:search,
    method: "GET"
    })
```

//gets a response from the giphy api

```
    .done(function(response){


    console.log(response.data);
```

// runs a for loop looks that puts the number of images that are in our search parameters into the dom

```
    for(i=0;i < re.length; i++) {
    var results = response.data[i].images.fixed_height.url;

    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src',results)
    $('#gif').prepend(img)

    }

    console.log(results);
    });
    });
```

Comment: the button that is already on the HTML works fine and runs but any button created using the jquery doesn't run

Comment: Try `$('body').on('click', 'button', function()..` instead of `$('button').on('click',function()...`.

Comment: Thank you that works. so that basically finds buttons on the body ?

Comment: Yes, `$('button').on('click',function()...` only considers buttons that exist when that statement is executed, the other approach considers all the buttons in the body.